# Is it possible to send a friend request on Xbox one to a PS4?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Minecraft, and I want to send a friend request to my friend, but we play on different consoles.

Is it possible to send a friend request to them?

Answer (score 3):

As of this week this has changed. Minecraft is now cross platform!

Answer (score 2):

**No, it is not possible to send a friend request to someone on a PS4 via Xbox.**

It is unlikely that you will **ever** be able to add them as a friend via Xbox.

In the future, you **might** be able to add them as a **Minecraft friend** and play with them.

PS4 cross-play for Minecraft hasn't happened ***yet*** because it has been Sony's [policy to not support cross-play](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/399425-minecraft-cross-play-ps4-other-consoles) with other platforms. However they have been under a lot of pressure to drop this policy, and have [recently allowed](https://www.theverge.com/2018/9/26/17905146/sony-fortnite-ps4-cross-play-support) Fortnite cross-play. This means that Minecraft cross-play **might** be around the corner.

It ***is*** possible to play Minecraft with friends between [Nintendo Switch](https://www.engadget.com/2018/06/21/minecraft-switch-bedrock-cross-platform-update/), [Xbox One, Android, and PC](https://www.engadget.com/2018/06/21/minecraft-switch-bedrock-cross-platform-update/).

> If you're reading this answer and enough time has passed, google around to see if the answer has changed! (or update this answer)

Comment: Minecraft is developed by a company owned my Microsoft. The pressure to allow cross-play does exist for Minecraft but the implications are very different then those surrounding the Fortnite deal. I highly doubt the possibility will ever become reality.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

I'm not sure where you got the idea that you could, but Xbox Live and the PS network are two separate networks. Friends between the two systems is unfortunately not something that is possible.